# Blanks in the Tape of a Turing Machine

Tags: formal-languages, automata, turing-machines

I used to have a lot of trouble with Turing Machines, primarily because I thought that in-between input symbols on the tape, one could have an arbitrary number of blanks, so every input would need to be delimited with start- and end-symbols, so the TM doesn't go reading an infinite number of blanks in search for more input symbols.

Is this true or not? Is it assumed that there are no blanks in-between input symbols on the tape?

Edit: moreover, when our TM reads in some input string, can we assume that there are no blanks in-between the symbols of our input string? Are there any conventions here?

Comment: It is common to make the _convention_ that the various inputs to a Turing machine are separated by single blanks. If important, many texts will make these conventions explicit at some point in the exposition.  For example, Cooper's _Computability Theory_ on p.39 explicitly sets out an input/output convention for Turing machines computing partial functions $\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Some authors stipulate that the input alphabet does not contain the blank symbol. This condition legislates away your concern.

Comment: Allowing  arbitrarily many blanks between input symbols looks like a very bad idea. You'd presumably want the output (if any) of the TM to depend only on the actual input, not on the interspersed blanks. (Otherwise, answer could be coded into the number of blanks.)  But this "depends only on ..." property of TMs is not decidable, so you'd be unable to tell what is and what isn't a "legitimate" TM in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

In Turing Machines, there are two types of alphabet: input alphabet and tape alphabet. Input alphabet includes symbols for input, blank symbol does not belong to input alphabet. Tape alphabet includes input alphabet and blank symbol. In addition, it may be additional symbols(i.e for marking start and end of inputs). So, initially, there is no blank in-between input symbols on the tape. After a several steps, TM manipulates the input and may put blanks between input symbols according to its algorithm.